# How to merge two JSON arrays into a single JSON array?

Tags: android, arrays

In the below code I have a one labelled switch on/off states. If default checked condition is on in that contains JSON array list

For off contains JSON array lists.

Now am having one button named as save. If am press on save button want to combine two JSON arrays into single JSON array want to pass as a parameters.

Please look at my code let me know where the mistake is.

Labelled switch:

```
simpleSwitch1.setOnToggledListener(new OnToggledListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwitched(LabeledSwitch labeledSwitch, boolean isChecked) {
                //mLigthOnOff.setOn(true);
                String isOn = "";

                if (isChecked) {
                    getCCTAndIntensityValues(API.SET_APP_SCHEDULE);



                }else {
                    getCCTAndIntensityValues(API.SET_APP_SCHEDULE);


                }
            }
        });
    }


public void getCCTAndIntensityValues (String schedulerType) {

            if (simpleSwitch1.isOn()) {
                int cct1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT1.getProgress()));
                int cct2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT2.getProgress()));
                int cct3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT3.getProgress()));
                int cct4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT4.getProgress()));
                int cct5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT5.getProgress()));
                int cct6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT6.getProgress()));
                int cct7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT7.getProgress()));
                int cct8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT8.getProgress()));
                int cct9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT9.getProgress()));
                int cct10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT10.getProgress()));
                int cct11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT11.getProgress()));
                int cct12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT12.getProgress()));


                int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));
                int intensity2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty2.getProgress()));
                int intensity3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty3.getProgress()));
                int intensity4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty4.getProgress()));
                int intensity5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty5.getProgress()));
                int intensity6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty6.getProgress()));
                int intensity7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty7.getProgress()));
                int intensity8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty8.getProgress()));
                int intensity9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty9.getProgress()));
                int intensity10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty10.getProgress()));
                int intensity11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty11.getProgress()));
                int intensity12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty12.getProgress()));

                try {

                    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
                    number.add(intensity1);
                    number.add(intensity2);
                    number.add(intensity3);
                    number.add(intensity4);
                    number.add(intensity5);
                    number.add(intensity6);
                    number.add(intensity7);
                    number.add(intensity8);
                    number.add(intensity9);
                    number.add(intensity10);
                    number.add(intensity11);
                    number.add(intensity12);

                    numberJson = new JSONArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {

                        numberJson.put(i, number.get(i));

                    }

                    ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues = new ArrayList<>();
                    cctvalues.add(cct1);
                    cctvalues.add(cct2);
                    cctvalues.add(cct3);
                    cctvalues.add(cct4);
                    cctvalues.add(cct5);
                    cctvalues.add(cct6);
                    cctvalues.add(cct7);
                    cctvalues.add(cct8);
                    cctvalues.add(cct9);
                    cctvalues.add(cct10);
                    cctvalues.add(cct11);
                    cctvalues.add(cct12);


                    cctJsonArray = new JSONArray();
                    if (cctJsonArray != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues.size(); i++) {

                            cctJsonArray.put(i, cctvalues.get(i));

                        }
                    }


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{

                int cct11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT1.getProgress()));
                int cct21 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT2.getProgress()));
                int cct31 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT3.getProgress()));
                int cct41 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT4.getProgress()));
                int cct51 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT5.getProgress()));
                int cct61 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT6.getProgress()));
                int cct71 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT7.getProgress()));
                int cct81 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT8.getProgress()));
                int cct91 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT9.getProgress()));
                int cct101 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT10.getProgress()));
                int cct111 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT11.getProgress()));
                int cct121 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT12.getProgress()));


                int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));
                int intensity2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty2.getProgress()));
                int intensity3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty3.getProgress()));
                int intensity4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty4.getProgress()));
                int intensity5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty5.getProgress()));
                int intensity6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty6.getProgress()));
                int intensity7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty7.getProgress()));
                int intensity8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty8.getProgress()));
                int intensity9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty9.getProgress()));
                int intensity10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty10.getProgress()));
                int intensity11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty11.getProgress()));
                int intensity12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty12.getProgress()));

                try {

                    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
                    number.add(intensity1);
                    number.add(intensity2);
                    number.add(intensity3);
                    number.add(intensity4);
                    number.add(intensity5);
                    number.add(intensity6);
                    number.add(intensity7);
                    number.add(intensity8);
                    number.add(intensity9);
                    number.add(intensity10);
                    number.add(intensity11);
                    number.add(intensity12);

                    numberJson1 = new JSONArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {

                        numberJson1.put(i, number.get(i));

                    }

                    ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues = new ArrayList<>();
                    cctvalues.add(cct11);
                    cctvalues.add(cct21);
                    cctvalues.add(cct31);
                    cctvalues.add(cct41);
                    cctvalues.add(cct51);
                    cctvalues.add(cct61);
                    cctvalues.add(cct71);
                    cctvalues.add(cct81);
                    cctvalues.add(cct91);
                    cctvalues.add(cct101);
                    cctvalues.add(cct111);
                    cctvalues.add(cct121);


                    cctJsonArray1 = new JSONArray();
                    if (cctJsonArray1 != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues.size(); i++) {

                            cctJsonArray1.put(i, cctvalues.get(i));

                        }
                    }


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }



mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                schedulerType=API.SET_APP_SCHEDULE;

                RequestAsyntask mRequestAsyntask = new RequestAsyntask(mContext);

                try {
                    RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                            .add("light_id", lightid)
                            .add("intensity", numberJson.toString()+numberJson1.toString())
                            .add("cct",cctJsonArray.toString()+cctJsonArray1.toString() ).build();

                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL + schedulerType).post(requestBody).build();

                    mRequestAsyntask.runDataRetriver(request, false);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Sending---" + BASE_URL + schedulerType + "\n" + "light_id:" + lightid + "\n" + "intensity:" + numberJson.toString()+numberJson1.toString() + "\n" + "cct:" + cctJsonArray.toString()+cctJsonArray1.toString());

                    mRequestAsyntask.setResponseListener(new ResponseCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(String response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Response:" + response);

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: Not clear. post expected and actual outputs.

Comment: What you want to do sum of the both `ArrayList` ?

Comment: intensity:[12,23,23,23,34,55,55,55,55,53,66,88,99,77,98,99,56,78,67,67,34,33,33,35]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Make a For loop and append numberJson1 to cctJsonArray1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberJson1.length(); i++) {
    cctJsonArray1.put(numberJson1.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

Hope this helps you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: light_id:01
    intensity:[40,49,48,56,62,72,63,55,54,49,0,0]
not working only 12 values are coming but want to show 24 values for intensity

Comment: for every time only what are last values are there it is sowing

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public JSONArray getMergeJson(ArrayList<JSONArray> abc){
  JSONArray result=null;
  JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
  obj.put("key",result);
  for(JSONArray tmp:abc){
    for(int i=0;i<tmp.length();i++){
     obj.append("key", tmp.getJSONObject(i));   ;
    }

   }
   return obj.getJSONArray("key");
 }
```